# Page navigation using button including a counter in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I want to add a next button on this home page (which also consists of a counter). But the counter is implemented inside a class so I am not able to use useHistory(). Also I cannot place the function routeChange() (error pops-up everytime) anywhere inside/outside the class, what to do?I am a newbie in React and I have been stuck around this problem for hours now please. Apologies if my question is too dumb for the platform. Following is my approach-

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button1 from "./Button1";
import { Button, } from 'reactstrap';
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
function Layout(){
const history = useHistory();
  const routeChange = () =>{
  let path = '/time'; 
  history.push(path);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">                    
        <Button color="primary"
         onClick={routeChange}
          >
            Next
        </Button>
    </div>
);
}

class  Home extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }
  
 
  incrementCount = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    });
  };

  decrementCount = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count - 1
    });
  };

  render() {
    let { count } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <div>
          <div class="count">
            <h3>Counter:</h3>
            <h1>{count}</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="buttons">
            <Button1 title={"-"} action={this.decrementCount} />
            <Button1 title={"+"} action={this.incrementCount} />
          </div>
          <div>
            {this.Layout()};
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

I am getting : this.Layout is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout is a component, so you need to call it like this:

```
<Layout />
```

If you want to send data to the component then you can use props:

```
<Layout count={this.state.count} />
```

Then in the Layout component you can add a props attribute to the function parameters:

```
function Layout(props)
```

and access it like this from within the Layout function:

```
props.count
```

It might be worth going through the tutorial on the [React website](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html). It can teach you the basics

Comment: Thank you soooo much for helping. Just a small issue, after clicking on the next button - this message comes "TypeError : Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: It means that you are calling the method push on something that is undefined. I'm not familiar with the useHistory hook from react-router so I can't help with the specifics of it. But you probably don't want to be putting that push directly in the function body. The function body will re-run every single time the component re-renders. You probably only want to run that function when the url changes